# Cannot create a new directory with Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am getting this error:

```
ErrorException
mkdir(): Permission denied
```

More details:

```
32. ErrorException
…/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Filesystem/­Filesystem.php 277
```

THe thing is I just setup Laravel 4. And the storage folder in app directory is writable. Everything in it seems writable.

I don't know where it is trying to create the directory. Clearly it's not in the storage directory. So where else is Laravel 4 creating dir?

Comment: It says right there, in the Filesystem module. This is probably a module to manage files on disk, not so strange that it would have a create directory feature. Make sure your webserver user has permissions to make folder in the app-dir.

Comment: You need set permissions on directory in which you're attempting to create dir

Comment: Goto that file, line 277 and add `dd($path);` right before  `mkdir`, it should dump what directory Laravel is trying to create.

Comment: That was my question. Where is it trying to write... I am looking through the logs and there is not enough information. I know the storage dir is writable.

Comment: Is there a way to make the logs clearer?

Comment: So you're saying this isn't custom code or a package you've pulled in, but Laravel's default build creating this error on your system?

Comment: Yes it's not custom code. But I did finally figure out what the problem was. It's just strange that I had to use dd(); PHP function to get the information needed to debug the problem. I even look into the server logs, there was not enough information.

Comment: What ended up being the problem/solution? I've run into the same issue.

Comment: WHat ended up being the solution? Please share cause i am having same problem along with many others. thanks